# Save plot in an image file using Matplolib

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot, save

I wrote a Python code for generating a `hexbin` plot and I would like to save it in a image file but it's impossible, the code creates a file but with nothing inside.

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

output_report = 'H:\_JUPYTER\_report\\'
df = pd.read_csv('H:\\_JUPYTER\\_report\\matrix_delta_speed.csv.bz2', compression='bz2', index_col='date', parse_dates=['date'], date_parser=lambda col: pd.to_datetime(col, errors='coerce'))

x = df.speed
y = df.delta

fig, ax = plt.subplots(ncols=1, sharey=True, figsize=(17, 10))
hb = ax.hexbin(x, y, gridsize=(150,150), cmap='inferno')
ax.axis([x.min(), x.max(), y.min(), y.max()])
ax.set_title('Delta vs. Speed')
ax.set_xlabel('Speed')
ax.set_ylabel('Delta')
cb = fig.colorbar(hb, ax=ax)
cb.set_label('counts')

plt.show()

plt.savefig(output_report+'Matrix.png', dpi=600)
```

I process to `savefig` but the file is completely white:

[image]

[image]

It's the same case for "hist" and other plot.

Comment: `output_report='H:\_JUPYTER\_report\\'` doesn't look good to me. Maybe `output_report='H:\\_JUPYTER\\_report\\'`

Comment: No that's good for me! Strange behavior on Windows. When you use a global variable for a path, you need to put double backslash at the end. When you set directly the path in a string as argument, you need to put all in double backslahs. The file is correctly create, but nothing inside. Thanks

Comment: May be call `savefig()` BEFORE `show()`

Comment: You might also want to check out *r* string literals, eg [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2081640/what-exactly-do-u-and-r-string-flags-do-and-what-are-raw-string-literals).

Comment: I try to do savefig() before and.... it's working! Very strange but why not! Thanks